# Starting point for learning etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, soft-question, homological-algebra, etale-cohomology

I am currently interested in learning etale cohomology. My background is what you could find in Hartshorne (mostly in chapter II and III) and I also have strong intuition from algebraic topology. I heard that there are several good references on this topic

- Kiehl, *Etale Cohomology and The Weil Conjectures*.
- Lei fu, *Etale Cohomology Theory*.
- Milne, *Lectures on Etale Cohomology*.
- Tamme, *Introduction to Etale Cohomology*.

I incline to use Leifu's book, but I wonder whether the author treats too many auxiliary results so I desire a roadmap for reading this book. Also, I appreciate any comment about the pros and cons of each of the aforementioned books. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My strong introduction is to read Milne's book, not his notes online--they're different, as well as SGA4.5 in conjunction.

Comment: Lie fu is a very good reference book. If you want to see clean and complete proof of a result and you prefer to read english you should check lie fu. But if you want to read a book about etale cohomology milne is a better book(especially the first three chapter) after that i recommend to check deligne lecture notes to get a good picture of important result and check sga or lie fu if you want to see the complete proofs.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Also, I appreciate any comment about the pros and cons of each of the aforementioned books. Thanks in advance."

**Answer:** I want to recommend Milnes "Etale cohomology" from 1980 - a self contained book. You need to know some commutative algebra ala Atiyah-Macdonald or Matsumuras book. The book "gives all details" and I believe it is better than the "Lectures on etale cohomology"-book.